# Regex expression avoiding URLs

Tags: regex

I'm trying to implement regular expression to find underlined text (text surrounded by underline symbol -> _), but I need to escape url links.

I have correct expression to find URL

`(http|ftp|https):\/\/([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&\/~+#-])?` (can be tested on https://regex101.com/), and a correct expression to find underlined text `(\s+|^|\B)(\_)(.+?)(\2)`.

How to combine them together to achieve specified logic?

PS I've tried to set `?!` before URL expression, but in this case only spaces falls into the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `?!` in a way to check if there is no part with for example http:// until the first occurrence of an underscore by using a negated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)

```
\S*(?:https?|ftp):\/\/\S+|(_(?![^_\n]*(?:https?|ftp):\/\/[^_\n]*_)[^_\n]+_)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/enoOm8/1)

Or you could use a quantifier with a fixed length in a negative lookbehind to assert that the current `_` is not part of a url

```
(?<!(?:http|ftp)s?://\S{0,1000})_(?![^_\n]*(?:http|ftp)s?://[^_\n]*)[^\n_]+_
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qC88Fv/1)

Comment: But if link contains underlines it will be filtered too. Example: http://google.com/some_link_with-underline (link word matches). So I need to exclude all matches inside URLs.

Comment: @Igor can there be a character following the last `_`? https://regex101.com/r/9NNiER/1

Comment: Yep, there may be a character, or ```_```may be the last symbol of string

Comment: @Igor What is the tool or language?

Comment: I'am using Swift and NSRegularExpression (It's objc tool to be precise)

Comment: You could get out of the way what you don't want to match, and capture in group 1 (highlighted in green) what you want to keep. `\S*(?:https?|ftp):\/\/\S+|(_(?![^_\n]*(?:https?|ftp):\/\/[^_\n]*_)[^_\n]+_)` See https://regex101.com/r/enoOm8/1

Comment: @Igor Of using a finite quantifier in a lookbehind `(?<!(?:http|ftp)s?://\S{0,1000})_(?![^_\n]*(?:http|ftp)s?://[^_\n]*)[^\n_]+_` https://regex101.com/r/qC88Fv/1